# SpreadsheetGear in WPF - binding cell value to property in MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, spreadsheetgear

Is it possible to bind an object's property to a SpreadsheetGear cell value in a MVVM application? Or alternatively is it possible to bind any WPF UI component to the cell value?

I need to reflect a value in a cell (IRange, holding a formula) in a property (or other WPF UI item) all of the time. Binding should be one way (from cell to property or cell to TextBlock.Text for example). What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am thinking about migrating my WinForms SSG app to WPF using MVVM - any thoughts?

Comment: To my knowledge, as of now, SpreadsheetGear doesn't support data binding or any MVVM at all. I hope I'm wrong though. At the moment, the option might be to handle EndCalculate or Calculate event elsewehre in the application but I hate this approach.